Bonnie and Clyde dogs
I am looking for a movie I think is from UK.
A couple is enjoying some time on the sand on the border of a lake, when a group of teenagers sits close to them and start annoying the couple, Loud music and so on.
The guy asks them to stop, teens does not want, ... things get more and more violent.
The couple will be tracked by the teens in the forest close to the lake, the guy will be attached to a tree with barbwire, and will die. The woman will manage to escape by stealing a car, will kill one of the teen and his dog called Bonnie (or Clyde). She will have a car accident in which she will end up in a garden. The family living there will at first start to help her. Then she will notice the same kind of dog called Clyde (or Bonnie).
She will try to escape by the bathroom, but at the same time, she father will learn that the woman killed his son...

Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

Is it Eden Lake (2008)?
Some matching descriptions from the wikipedia page:

Finding the gang in the woods after nightfall, Steve demands the return of his belongings, only to be attacked by the knife wielding teens. In the scuffle, Brett's dog is mortally knifed, fuelling Brett's lust for revenge.
At daybreak, Jenny sees Steve tied up in barbed wire in a small clearing.
She makes it to town, crashing into a fence at a large backyard party. (...)
  Brett's father notices the van on his lawn, and one of the parents receives a call informing her of the dead gang members - children of the adults at the house. (...) Brett has convinced the parents that the teens have been sadistically murdered by Jenny and Steve. 

Only thing I could not match on the fly are the dog names.
